# @Transactional не создает транзакцию hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, java

В файле бинов спринга имеются такие строки:

```
<context:annotation-config />   
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pack"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

Боб, в котором объявлена фабрика сессий:

```
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSourceConfiguration.dataSource());

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
//        props.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        factory.setHibernateProperties(props);
        factory.setMappingResources("com/pack/Item.hbm.xml");

        return factory;
    }
```

Бины dataSource и sessionFactory отдельно работают нормально, думаю, проблема не в них. Имеется DAO:

```
@Repository(value = "itemDaoHibernateImpl")
public class ItemDaoHibernateImpl implements ItemDao {

    @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory factory;

    public void setFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public Session session() {
        return factory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void create(Item item) {
        session().save(item);
    }
```

Сессии в нем не открываю, т.к. хочу заставить спринг делать это. Имеется класс Service c таким вот методом:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void create(Item item) {
    dao.create(item);
}
```

При запуске этого метода падает вот такой эксепшн:

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction`

Делал как [сказано тут](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), ещё пару гайдов прочитал левых, но в них сессия открывается  руками в каждом методе в ДАО, а мне это не нужно.
Как сделать, чтоб работало? Где ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порылся в карманах, нашел свой конфиг:

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.sprigframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configurationClass">
      <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.charset">UTF-8</prop>
      </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>...</value>
        </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Как видите, `hibernate.current_session_context_class` не задан (совсем как у вас то есть) и все работает. Почему? Spring сам заинжектит свой [`SpringSessionContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/SpringSessionContext.html) для поддержки транзакций в scope-е своих сессий и запросов.

Comment: Нужно ли помечать @Transactional все методы в сервисе? У меня, например, есть метод в сервисе, который дёргает только одну ДАО операцию. Стало быть, прерваться он может. Или нужно метить всё?

Comment: @argamidon, аннотируются методы, которые вы хотите обернуть в транзакцию. Аннотирование класса равносильно аннотированию отдельно каждого метода. Если вам нужна транзакция только на одном методе - его и помечайте.

Comment: Я пометил аннотацией сервисный метод, который вызывает сразу две команды (метода) из ДАО. Работает нормально. Но вот метод который вызывает всего один ДАО метод я не помечал @Transactional. в результате словил эксепшн -  
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Comment: @argamidon, да, нужно пометить всех, кто дергает DAO (чтобы в DAO заинжектилась сессия).

Comment: @Nofate ♦ большое спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить аннотацию @Transactional к классу дао.

```
@Repository(value = "itemDaoHibernateImpl")
@Transactional
public class ItemDaoHibernateImpl implements ItemDao {
    ....
}
```

Comment: да ну. ничего это не дало

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил. Удалил параметр из хиба `hibernate.current_session_context_class`, который имел значение thread. Это работает, но не понимаю, как тогда хиб  будет определять,  создавать новую сессию или гетить существующую методом currentSession().

Comment: @argamidon, а покажите, как у вас в спринге объявлена `sessionFactory`.

Comment: обновил первый пост. закомментировал ту строку, и работа пошла. Что нужно указывать в этом параметре при работе хиб+спринг

Comment: одновременно используете xml, аннотации и java config - однако...

Comment: Нет, я уже всё отрефакторил в аннотации.